# looping throught worhsheet excel vba and return data on another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub CreateTableD()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
'Dim n As Long

Set WB = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set WS1 = WB.Worksheets("List1")
Set WS2 = WB.Worksheets("List2")

i = 1
k = 1
'While Not IsEmpty(WS1.Cells(i, 1))
Do While WS1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    If (WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Depo" And WS1.Cells(i, 8).Value = "CZK") Then
        WS2.Cells(k + 1, 4).Value = WS1.Cells(i, 7).Value
        WS2.Cells(k + 2, 4).Value = WS1.Cells(i, 7).Value
        WS2.Cells(k + 1, 7).Value = "79010000"
        WS2.Cells(k + 2, 7).Value = "79010000"




        ElseIf (WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Loan" And WS1.Cells(i, 8).Value = "CZK") Then

        WS2.Cells(k + 1, 4).Value = WS1.Cells(i, 7).Value
        WS2.Cells(k + 2, 4).Value = WS1.Cells(i, 7).Value
        WS2.Cells(k + 1, 7).Value = "75010000"
        WS2.Cells(k + 2, 7).Value = "75010000"


        k = k + 2
    End If
    i = i + 1
'Wend
Loop



Range("D1").Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CZK"
 End Sub
```

Hi. I have a code, but it doesnt work properly. If two conditions are satisfied it must return interest on another worksheet and also some static data( which is in the code) I've shown the right result on second picture.

[first worksheet with conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1bhf.png)

[on this picture i showed what i need to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlpP5.png)

Comment: Please write a specific question about what your code is trying to achieve and how it isn't working. Does it throw an error at a specific line?

Comment: i've post the second picture. its easy to understand what i'm trying to achive on the picture. code doesn't have any erros and it works, but i think its rewrite the fiirst part of condiotion, so i have only data with second condition on the result list

Comment: if the code returns incorrect data, then it does not work. it is like saying _my car works, just the engine does not run_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are only incrementing `k` when it is a loan.

```
If (WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Depo" And WS1.Cells(i, 8).Value = "CZK") Then

ElseIf (WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Loan" And WS1.Cells(i, 8).Value = "CZK") Then
    k = k + 2
End If
```

Incrementing `k` when eith condition is True will fix the problem.

```
If (WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Depo" And WS1.Cells(i, 8).Value = "CZK") Then
    k = k + 2
ElseIf (WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Loan" And WS1.Cells(i, 8).Value = "CZK") Then
   k = k + 2
End If
```

I usually create a separate function to handle adding data to a table.  Breaking up the code into smaller units helps simplify debugging.

Here is how I would write it.

```
Sub CreateTableD()
    Dim x As Long

    With Worksheets("List1")
        For x = 2 To .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(x, 8).Value = "CZK" Then
                If .Cells(x, 4).Value = "Depo" Then
                    AddList2Entry .Cells(x, 7).Value, "79010000"
                    AddList2Entry .Cells(x, 7).Value, "79010000"
                ElseIf .Cells(x, 4).Value = "Loan" Then
                    AddList2Entry .Cells(x, 7).Value, "75010000"
                    AddList2Entry .Cells(x, 7).Value, "75010000"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Sub AddList2Entry(interest As Double, StaticValue As Double)
    Dim newRow As Long
    With Worksheets("List2")
        newRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(newRow, "D").Value = interest
        .Cells(newRow, "G").Value = StaticValue
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]